# Sharepoint Foundation shows "Publish" at the top

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have created a few sites on Sharepoint Foundation but one of my sites shows "Publish" in NAV bar at the top and none of the other sites have that on it. The users can see it but it is inactive for them. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the same ...

Comment: unable to because this site says I need 10 posts to be able to post images

Comment: SharePoint Foundation doesn't have the Publishing Feature? Can you confirm this is the case by going to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Manage Site Features and verify that 'SharePoint Server Publishing' is there or not?

Comment: You are correct, it was not there.

Answer (score 1):

I actually stumbled upon the corrective action. I went to Page, Library settings, and then versioning settings. Once there, I turned off the Content Approval and the word Publish went away. Thanks for the input from everyone that responded.